# How to specify the love character in NSSString?

Tags: objective-c

How do you specify the [heart character](http://keakaj.com/mac-heart.html) in NSSString? I am implementing a network protocol and want to send this as the heartbeat.

This is the Unicode info from character viewer:

```
Unicode: U+1F493 (U+D83D U+DC93), UTF-8: F0 9F 92 93
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to type it directly into a string constant in Xcode:

```
NSString *heart = @"";
```

If you need to convert it to bytes in a specific encoding, use `NSData`, like this:

```
// Specify the encoding that you need
NSData* heartData = [heart dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

With an instance of `NSData` in hand, you can access its `bytes` and `length` to copy into the heartbeat message.

Comment: +1 for the easiest way. Everybody forgets you can just head to the character viewer and drop in whatever character you want.

Comment: @Josiah Yeah, for you, maybe. What about the poor slob who has to maintain the code?

Comment: @trudyscousin, I really am not sure how to interpret that. So I think I will just let that go. I simply +1ed the answer. It is pretty much the easiest way. Do you know of an alternative that is faster?

Comment: Well, none faster, but for maintenance, I'd favor using the form \uXXXX for such a character.